# Gather data cyclically from OPC server

Tags: java, opc-ua, opc

I want to acquire historical data cyclically from an OPC server every few minutes. Should I create a separate thread at the client end for the purpose or use some kind of subscription ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriptions are for real-time data.

Historical data is read via the HistoryRead service, which you would indeed need to call periodically.

But why would you read historical data cyclically instead of once at the start followed by receiving live updates for the values you're interested in? Or at least read the historical data much further apart than every few minutes?

Comment: I need to acquire raw historical data from servers that gather info from PLC signals and store it in a database.  Now wouldn't reading all the data cyclically for all the signals be easier than maintaining a listener for each signal node and updating accordingly?

Comment: Yes if all you're doing is transferring the historical data from one place to another and you don't need it in realtime then reading the history cyclically should be okay.